# Convert one schema object to another

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Let's say you have the following blueprint object and result object.

```js
const blueprintObj = {
    propertyOne: 'One',
    propertyTwo: 'Two',
    propertyThree: 'Three',
    propertyFour: 'Four',
}

const resultObject = {
    propertyOne: 'One',
    propertyThree: 'Three',
    propertyFour: 'Four',
    propertyFive: 'Five'
}
```

Notice that `resultObject` is missing `propertyTwo` but has an extra `propertyFive`. I've wrote a script to do this for me:

```js
for (const data in resultObject) {
    if (!blueprintObj[data]) {
        delete resultObject[data];
    }
}

for (const data in blueprintObj) {
    if (!resultObject[data]) {
        resultObject[data] = blueprintObj[data];
    }
}
```

This works... except that `resultObject` is actually a document in a MongoDB database. How would I do this if `blueprintObj` was a regular object, and `resultObject` was a MongoDB document?

Comment: Since you are trying to update a document - use an _update_ method / operation.. Also, look into the Updates with Aggregation Pipeline feature in the MongoDB Manual.

Comment: @prasad_ Yes, I have tried that, but I couldn't get it to work. I previously asked a question already that included my database, can you please check that out? I made this question because that one was a bit complicated.

Comment: You can include the code  / query you had tried in your question post. Someone can suggest a correction or improvement to solve the issue you are facing.

Comment: @prasad_ I know this was an old post, but can you check my previous post? I still can't solve the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69332046/removing-and-adding-properties-according-to-a-schema